# How to append/use the matched value that UISearchBar found during search in swift?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, dictionary, uisearchbar, swift5

As you can see here in my code, I have nested Array/Dictionary and the search I have to make in different keys together, just like student_name, (student_name) is inside in student Dictionary, everything working perfectly, but the only issue I am facing here is, whatever searchBar found I have to show in cell but due to nested dictionary I am not getting how to show in cell.

```
cell.nameLbl.text =  (What should I write here to show found values???)
```

if I have to create one more array to append values that searchBar found then question is what should I write in code ( what I am appending? )

```
var foundName:[String] = [] (Declared global variable to save only string that already matched)

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredData = schoolData.filter{(item:School?) -> Bool in

           return ((item?.resultMap["teacher"] as? String)?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil) ||
                ((item?.resultMap["class"] as? String)?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil) ||
                ((((item?.resultMap["student"]) as? [String: Any?])?["student_name"] as? String)?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil)
        }
        foundName.append(contentsOf: (what should I write here .. ))

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create an array that holds the search values. This array should be populated in func searchBar.

> cell.nameLbl.text =  (What should I write here to show found values???)

```
var foundNames: [String] = []
cell.nameLbl.text = foundNames[indexPath.row]
```

Modify search func to populate the values found and use map to return only the results (of any of the fields searched) as string array. I've provided an example below of how you can convert the schoolData object to return an array of school names.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar? = nil, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let filteredData = schoolData.filter { item in
        return (item.name?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil)
    }
    foundNames = filteredData.map({
        ($0.name ?? "")
    })
}
```

Here's is the sample data I used.

```
var schoolData: [School] = [School(id: 1, name: "First"),
    School(id: 2, name: "Second"),
    School(id: 3, name: "Third"),
    School(id: 4, name: "Four")]


class School {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but thats not the answer I am looking for, Here is the json that I I have to use for search : teacher, class, student_name . Json is  {
  "Study": {
   "School": [{
    "school_name": "New York School",
    "teacher": "Micheal",
    "class": "Standard First",
    "student": {
     "student_name": "David"
    },
    "schoolTimming": {
     "startTimming": "Mar,13 2020"
    }
   }]
  }
 }

Comment: I get an error in item?.resultMap. Send me the code that converts the json to the object you are using in searchBar func.

Comment: I added the answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer of my question, I figured it out finally.

```
 if let title = item?.resultMap["teacher"] as? String, title.prefix(2) == searchText  {
                    self.foundName.append(item?.resultMap["teacher"] as? String ?? "")
                }
```

For cell thats the code I had wrote,

```
cell.nameLbl.text =  foundName[indexPath.row]
```